# Parse REST API vs Parse JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, rest, parse-platform

We are building a web & mobile chat application. The use case is that consumers can chat to our customer service using an android mobile app. Our backend team will reply to the users using the web app.

The web app will also have features to upload posts to the parse database that will be visible on the users newsfeed, query the parse database for items/transactions & upload new product SKUs to the database.

For the chat we will be using a service like [Layer](https://layer.com/)/[Pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com/)/[Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) along with [Parse](https://parse.com) as the database. Will this architecture work well ?

Also, for the web app, should we use the native [Parse JS SDK](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide)? or develop a Node.JS/Express.JS application using the [Parse REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a server side Node.js app, I'd say the JS SDK works fine. I've used the REST API to develop JS Client-side plugins (there's prbly a JS way using RequireJS) and to interface Parse to other languages such as R. A couple of pastebins as samples:

- Javascript - http://pastebin.com/eqAs5EDT
- REST - http://pastebin.com/7TtZUwzy